# if $\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s)= f(t,s,A,X_s)$ is $f$ necessarily a transition function?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(X_t)$ a stochastic process and $(\mathcal F_t)$ its natural filtration. For me, if for all Borel set $A$, $$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s\}=f(t,s,A,X_s),\tag{1}$$ then $$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s\}=\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_s\}.$$

Therefore, $(X_t)$ is a Markov process.

**Q1)** Am I right ?

But in my lecture, they want $$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s\}=P_{t,s}(A,X_s),$$
where $(P_{t,s})$ is a familly of transition function.

**Q2)** So, I guess that $(1)$ is not enough to be a markov process, is it ? But maybe that the function $f(t,s,\cdot ,\cdot )$ is automatically a transition function whenever $(1)$ hold ?  If not, could someone provide a counter example ?

Comment: Q1) yes; Q2) not really "automatically". $f$ is defined non-uniquely, up to values on a set $B$ with $\mathrm{P}(X_s \in B) = 0$. But, in a separable complete metric space, there is a version, which is a transition function (i.e. the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation holds).